# Безопасно ли отдавать apk-файл?

Tags: unity3d

В Unity сделал билд с опцией "Development Bild". Насколько безопасно отдавать этот файл 3-й стороне?

Comment: что означает "безопасно"?

Comment: @Эникейщик, сможет ли посторонний из этого apk получить исходный код?

Comment: юнити проекта... можно и из релизной так-то код получить, поэтому большого смысла опасаться я не вижу

Comment: в том, виде как у разработчика (с комментариями и пр), вряд ли. Но вообще сможет. Есть даже программы, которые этот код и апк на тарелочке выдают.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тогда получается любой может взять чужую программу, поменять цвет, шрифт, картинки. И продавать как свою?